# Domain of $h(x) = \log_2 (x^2+4)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, logarithms

I am setting the $x^2+4 > 0$ and solving, but this leaves me with a question I can't seem to understand.
The resource I'm using is saying the domain is $(-\infty, \infty)$; $x$ is a set of all Real numbers.

I don't understand how, considering I would need to square a negative number during my search for what works, maybe I'm missing a key piece of information on rules of domain here?

Steps:

\begin{align*}
x^2 + 4 & \geq 0\\
x^2 & \geq -4\\
x & \geq \sqrt{-4}
\end{align*}
This is where I'm stuck.

Comment: Go back one step. $x^2>-4$ holds for all real $x$. Indeed, $x^2\ge0$ holds for all real $x$.

Comment: "*x > sqrt(-4)*" $\,$ This makes no sense, because "$\sqrt{-4}$" does not exist in real numbers, and "$\gt$" does not exist in complex numbers.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Ah ok, so I guess this is where I'm missing it. I get that any squared is positive. I guess I missed somewhere that I should just stop at the x^2 > 4 and just say, it can be any  real number because it'll be squared and become positive making the statement true ultimately. Do I have that correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align}&x^2 + 4  > 0 \\\iff{}& x^2 > -4\\\iff{}& x\in\mathbb R;\end{align} therefore, $\log_2 (x^2+4)$ has domain $\mathbb R.$

Note that technically, both directions of argument are required:

- although $\boldsymbol{x > 0}\implies x>-7,$

  the domain of $\log (\boldsymbol x)$ is not $[-7,\infty);$
- although $x>3\implies \boldsymbol{x > 0},$

  the domain of $\log (\boldsymbol x)$ is not $[3,\infty).$

> \begin{align*}
> x^2 & \geq -4\\
> x & \geq \sqrt{-4}\end{align*}

Incidentally, $\:x^2\ge9\:$ does not imply that $\:x\ge\sqrt9;$ take for example $x=-5.$

In fact, when $c$ is real, \begin{gather}x^2\ge c^2\;\iff\; x\le-|c| \quad\text{or}\quad |c|\le x,\tag1\\x^2\ge9\;\iff\; x\le-\sqrt9 \quad\text{or}\quad \sqrt9\le x.\end{gather} In any case, since $(-4)$ isn't the square of a real number, equivalence $(1)$ doesn't hold.

Answer (score 1):

The argument of this logarithm is always positive, whatever the value of x. You don't need so solve the inequality $x^2 + 4 > 0$. Therefore, the domain is in fact $(-\infty, \infty)$.